# Warning: oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Tags: php, oracle

Hi I'm looking for some help regarding above problem LINE 66. I can see there are several mysql user who faced the same problems as me but after trying the solution it seems like the error still there. Here is my codes.

check_login.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))

{

    $stmt2= oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."' ")or die(oci_error());
    $check2 = oci_execute($stmt2);

         //Gives error if user dosen't exist
     //$check3 = oci_num_rows($check2); <-- if I uncomment this, it will result in an error too.

       if (!$check2) //it supposely if($check3<0)
       {
       header('location: index.php?error=10');
            exit();
       }
       else
       {
        while($info2=oci_fetch_array($check2)) // <----- Error in this line (line 66).
            {
            $pass=$info2['password'];
            //gives error if the password is wrong
            if ($_POST['password'] != $pass)
            {
            header('location: index.php?error=14');
            exit();
            }
            else
            {

             // if login is ok then we add a cookie
            $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
        $hour = time() + 86400;

            setcookie(ID_site, $_SESSION['id'], $hour);
            setcookie(Pass_site, $_SESSION['password'], $hour);

            //then redirect them to the members area
                if ($info2['role']=='admin')
                {
                header('Location: homeAdmin.php');
                }
                elseif ($info2['role']=='staff')
                {
                header('Location: homeStaff.php');
                }
                elseif ($info2['role']=='student')
                {
                header('Location: homeStudent.php');
                }
                else
                {
                header('Location: index.php');
                }

            } //end else

         } //end while

}//end else

}// end if submit
 else
{
 header('Location: index.php');
 }
```

Comment: You could start by reading the manual. [`oci_execute`](http://php.net/manual/function.oci-execute.php) returns a `boolean`. [`oci_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.oci-fetch-array.php) takes a *statement* resource

Comment: Also, The OCI8 extension supports [parameter binding](http://www.php.net/manual/function.oci-bind-by-name.php). You should use it to avoid possible SQL injection exploits via your `id` POST parameter

Comment: Thanks Phil. My mistake. I'm to focus on the line without remember about boolean thing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[oci_execute always returns a boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php). Basically, oci_execute returns whether the db statement worked, but it stores the *result* of the statement back in the passed variable that held the statement in the first place. So if you change the error line to this, you should be fine:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt2, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
```

Comment: Thanks Dimono, problem solved!

But now I have another problem with the same code.

Here,
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\..\connection.php:10) in C:\xampp\htdocs\..\check_login.php on line 72

-------------
header('location: index.php?error=14'); // line 72

Comment: connection.php <?php $conn = oci_connect("system","db","");
if (!$conn)
{
echo "Failed to connect to Oracle.";
}
else 
{
echo "Successfully connected with Oracle DB";
} ?>

Comment: You can't send a header after you've sent data.

Comment: Then what u suggest me to do? Should I just remove the header in connection.php?

Comment: That's a discussion that's beyond the scope of this help request. The short version is if you're going to rely on html headers to do things, those headers **must** be sent before any page contents, without exception. If that means you need to juggle the order in which you do things, then so be it.

Comment: No problem. If I helped you with your initial problem, it's good form to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark below the vote arrows.

Comment: what if I get this error? Warning: oci_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given